# Get '(401)Unauthorized' error when calling SharePoint web service

Tags: java, web-services, sharepoint, axis

I use Axis 1.4 to generate java classes from http://10.0.0.22/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

I use following code to access web service:

```
javax.xml.rpc.Service service = new ListsLocator();
ListsSoapStub stub = SharePointWSDL.newLists(new URL("http://10.0.0.22/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"), service);
stub.setUsername(username);
stub.setPassword(password);
com.microsoft.schemas.sharepoint.soap.GetListCollectionResponseGetListCollectionResult lcr = stub.getListCollection();
```

I get "(401)Unauthorized" error.

How can I use java classes which are generated by Axis to access SharePoint web service?

Comment: Does the account you are using have access to the site? Also, why are you using IP address?

Comment: Account used have access to the site. SharePoint is installed on local  machine, so I use local IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Basic Authentication is not enabled on IIS. When I enable Basic Authentication, I can access SharePoint web serivce.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ListsSoap12Stub try this instead of ListsSoapStub. This worked for me.